# I'm trying this example of sessionStorage from an HTML5 tutorial but it is not working and nothing is changing in the 'rightbox' section

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, innerhtml, session-storage

The 'rightbox' section must show the key and value entered in the form after they were stored using sessionStorage.
I tried Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Opera browsers. The code didn't work on any of them.

Here is the code:

```js
function doFirst() {
  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  button.addEventListener('click', saveStuff, false);
}

function saveStuff() {
  var one = getElementById('one').value;
  var two = getElementById('two').value;
  sessionStorage.setItem(one, two);
  display(one);
}

function display(one) {
  var rightbox = document.getElementById('rightbox');
  var thedata = sessionStorage.getItem(one);
  rightbox.innerHTML = 'Name of variable: ' + one + '<br />Value: ' + thedata;
}

window.addEventListener('load', doFirst, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="leftbox">
    <form>
      <p>(key) One: <input type="text" id="one"></p>
      <p>(value) Two: <textarea id="two"></textarea></p>
      <p><input type="button" id="button" value="Save"></p>
    </form>
  </section>
  <section id="rightbox">
    Nothing yet!
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Didn't you see the errors in the JavaScript console? Why didn't you fix them before posting?

Comment: Where and how can I see the errors? I'm using VS Code.

Comment: I don't know how to see it in VS Code. I test in a browser and use the Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following block from your code:

```
function saveStuff() {
    var one = getElementById('one').value;
    var two = getElementById('two').value;
    console.log(one, two);
    sessionStorage.setItem(one, two);
    display(one);
}
```

You need to use `document.getElementById()` instead of just `getElementById`. That will solve your issue.

Furthemore, you have used `document.getElementById()` properly in your first function, so make sure to check for errors in the browser console next time before posting a question. That will help you in long run.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById